Supabase local edge function is not printing console.log statements to the terminal
I have a Supabase edge function that runs locally. The function uses express.js for routing.
It basically looks like this:
import "jsr:@supabase/functions-js/edge-runtime.d.ts";

// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@5.0.0"
import express from 'npm:express@4.21.1';
import cors from 'npm:cors@2.8.5';
import { isUsernameAvailable } from "./endpoints/entity/is-username-available.ts";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.all('/api/*', (req, _res, next) => {
  req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, '');
  console.log("TESTING");
  next();
});

app.get('/entity/is-username-available', isUsernameAvailable);


This function works fine, but console.log statements are simply not working - no matter where in the code I put it.
I have the latest Supabase, Deno, and Docker versions. Supabase 2.1.1, Deno 2.1.4, and Docker 4.37.1
What am I missing?
